# How do I set up masked sub-domain routing to an external domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I need to set up masked sub-domain routing so that visitors to sub-domain(a) are routed to a page on an external domain (b) which is on a different server.

This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mymarketingstrategy.youngwazy.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mymarketingwizard.io%{REQUEST_URL} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

This setup currently routes the visitor from `mymarketingstrategy.youngwazy.com` to `https://www.mymarketingwizard.io`.  However, there are 2 issues with this current set up.

1) The URL is not masked - it changes to `https://www.mymarketingwizard.io` when it should remain `mymarketingstrategy.youngwazy.com`.

2) The destination route needs to be `https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/landing_kv`

What changes do I need to make to my htaccess file to achieve this?

Comment: Is "external domain" hosted on different server?

Comment: yes it is. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files (and have permissions to change them)?

Comment: possibly - I will have to check.  If so, is that where the problem lies? Am I doing things incorrectly by trying to do this by the .htaccess file?

Comment: Well, you should [never use .htaccess if you can change conf files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) (.htaccess is actually for shared hosting environments where you have access only to your folder).

Comment: ah ok - so if I can get access to the conf files and the sub-domain is not on shared hosting then I should look at the conf files instead?

Comment: That is a general guideline - even if it is doable in .htaccess, you should do it in .conf (using .htaccess comes with performance penalty)

Answer (score 1):

Try using mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mymarketingstrategy.youngwazy.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/landing_kv%{REQUEST_URL} [P,NC,L,QSA]
```

(keep in mind that hrefs in html content will not be modified!)